# Alternative to eval() in node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a script that runs during our build process in Jenkins right before `npm install`. My issue is that I need to download a JavaScript file from an external resource and read a variable from it.

```
unzipper.on('extract', () => { 
  const content = fs.readFileSync(`${outputDir}/js/en.js`, 'utf8');
  eval(content); // Less smellier alternative?

  if (obj) {
    const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${outputDir}/public/data.json`, str);
  } else {
    throw 'Variable `obj` not found';
  }
});
```

I know that *"`eval` is evil"*, but any suggested alternatives I've found online don't seem to work. 
I have tried different variations of `new Function(obj)()`, but Node seems to exit the script after (the `if`-case never runs).

Ideas?

Comment: what is the variable? Is it just hard coded or is it like a method?

Comment: @epascarello, it's a fairly big js object.

Comment: If you know the provenance of the script and trust it (with a high level of trust), it's fine to use `eval`. It's blindly using it for arbitrary script that's evil.

Comment: It's only evil if used inappropriately, especially client side or in places where the javascript input can not be guaranteed safe. Doing `new Function` is literally the same as `eval` apart from the need to call the new function declaration to run the evaluated code. Eval is typically also avoided because its slow, but there's no other way to evaluate JS - an alternative would be to write some kind of Regex parser yourself but that might be too complicated for the task - especially if you're ok with the above..

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah I thought so too. This is probably the first time I use `eval` in prod and had to be sure I am not missing a, unseen to me, pitfall. The resource is trusted, but beyond my control.

Comment: As @Adriani6 mentions, there is a performance hit, since you're basically evaluating JavaScript from within JavaScript, so there's an Inception tax :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I know. In the context of running this on building my bundle, the extra time is negligible. This isn't run on a client.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the reason I was trying out `new Function` is due to what the bibl... I mean the MDN says: *More importantly, a third-party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.*

Comment: So the js file starts with something like `obj = {.....` ? You can prepend `module.exports.` to it, write to a temp file  and then  `require` it.

Comment: @georg I would, if only I had access to said file :/ It's beyond my control to change it unfortunately...

Comment: @Chris: you do have read access, as it's obvious from your code. What I meant is literally: `content += '; module.exports=obl'; writeFile(temp, content);obj=require(temp)`

Comment: @georg, oh sorry. I thought you meant write access to the file. I'll try this.

Comment: @georg, do you want to write that as an answer?

Comment: @Chris: after some thought, I've found a better option.

Comment: I don't see a problem with using `eval()` here if this is the problem you have to solve (e.g. can't change the overall design for how this code gets run).  You said the code was trusted (it has to be or running it inside your program is a problem no matter how you run it).  So, what specifically are you concerned about here?

Comment: @jfriend00 it's more principal than anything. If there is a "safer" way to achieve what I need, then why not go with that? Even though I'm quite aware of the risks of using `eval`, I've never *really* used it. So I had to ask for feedback/suggestions.

Comment: If the code is trusted, I think `eval()` is appropriate in this circumstance.  If the code isn't trusted, there is no alternative that's going to run it here in context and somehow make untrusted code safe.  You haven't shared what the purpose of this code is, but if all you want is an object out of it, you could put the code in a wrapper and then run that code in another process, stringify the resulting object and bring the JSON back to this process.  That assumes the resulting `obj` doesn't have any circular references or references to existing globals in it.

Comment: @jfriend00 are you referring to `child_process`? I tried that, but didn't get very far. You are more than welcome to write an answer :)

Comment: Unless, you describe otherwise, it doesn't sound like there's any security reason to use a separate process here and that would just complicate things.  `eval()` seems fine to me for running trusted code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since node.js provides the [API](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) to talk to the V8 runner directly, it might be a good idea to use it. Basically, it's the API used by node's `require` under the hood.

Assuming the js file in question contains the variable `obj` we're interested in, we do the following:

- read the code from the file
- append `; obj` to the code to make sure it's the last expression it evaluates
- pass the code to V8 for evaluation
- grab the return value (which is our `obj`):

```
    const fs = require('fs'),
        vm = require('vm');

    const code = fs.readFileSync('path-to-js-file', 'utf8');
    const obj = vm.runInNewContext(code + ';obj');
```

Comment: And, how is this better than just using `eval()`?  Your answer would be more meaningful if you offered an idea.  The goal here presumably isn't just to replace `eval()`, but to offer something better. Personally, I haven't yet seen what's wrong with using `eval()` in this context since the code is apparently trusted.

Comment: I like this answer -- it is "better" because it's *safer*. Since it runs in a new empty virtual machine "sandbox", there is no access to the parent's runtime context or variables (unless they were explicitely passed to the vm).

Comment: I'm wondering if there would be any benefit to changing the last line to `require.cache.obj = { exports: vm.runInNewContext(code + ';obj') };` so that other modules could also have access to obj via require?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is heavily based on **@georg**'s comments, but since it helped me I'll provide it as an alternative answer.

Explanation in the comments.

```
let content = fs.readFileSync(`${outputDir}/js/en.js`, 'utf8');
content += '; module.exports=obj'; // Export "obj" variable

fs.writeFileSync(`${outputDir}/temp`, content); // Create a temporary file
const obj = require(`${outputDir}/temp`); // Import the variable from the temporary file
fs.unlinkSync(`${outputDir}/temp`); // Remove the temporary file
```

Comment: I'm curious to know why you didn't go with georg's answer.  Seems like all the extra disk I/O is going to slow things down.

Comment: @Jeff I don't recall to be honest, but I think georg's answer didn't work straight away without modifications.